# How to trigger visual transformation upon focus prior to typing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, text-cursor

Is there a way to trigger the `VisualTransformation` upon focus just prior to user typing?

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = modifier,
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { input ->
        text = input
    },
    label = {
        Text("Input Here")
    },
    placeholder = {
        Text("$")
    }
)
```

In this case, I'm looking for a way to put the cursor in `front` or `after` the `$` dollar sign upon focus

[image]

[image]

Something like this

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to place the cursor after the placeholder text? The placeholder text will be removed when the user starts typing.

Comment: If the cursor is placed after the placeholder text, it gives the impression that the text is prefilled, and any text that the user types will continue after the placeholder text, which is not the case with placeholder text.

Comment: Im attempting to migrate/refactor a similar existing functionality of a View counterpart, not sure if this can be solved by a VisualTransformation